# How to portably implement `test path1 -ef path2`?

Tags: shell

I've been using `-ef` as an argument to `test` for some time on macos and linux, and just noticed that it is not standardized.  Given that neither  `readlink` nor `realpath` are standardized as shell utilities, how does one portably determine if two paths refer to the same file?

Answer (score 2):

Believe it or not, I think `ls` is your best bet; the `-i` option is defined to output the serial number prior to the file name.

```
$ ls -i foo.txt
12893115840 foo.txt
```

It doesn't matter if the file name contains newlines, because we are guaranteed to only care about the first field of the first line. Thus,

```
get_serial_number () {
  ls -i "$1" | awk '{print $1; exit}'
}

same_file () {
    i1=$(get_serial_number "$1")
    i2=$(get_serial_number "$2")
    [ "$i1" = "$i2" ]
}

if same_file "$file1" "$file2"; then
    ...
```

As Charles Duffy points out, this only checks that the serial number for the two files are the same; that can be true if for different files that live on different file systems.

Comment: In an *ideal* world we'd check not just the inode number but also the filesystem (should there be a portable way to identify it) so as to catch collisions between identical inode numbers on different mounted filesystems. Granted, that's a fairly low-probability occurrence.

Comment: That's true. I also didn't check how `-ef` handles symlinks, so you may or may not want to use the `-H` option with `ls`.